# How to Handle Durations Without Using Moment.js Durations Feature?

Tags: javascript

Up until now, I've been using Moment.js durations feature to handle all my "length of time" needs. As Moment.js is no longer being supported, I would like to move away from it. However, I've used it for so long and now find it difficult to transition. What are other methods I can use to handle durations?

Comment: You can use Date-fns , it covers almost all functionality of Moment.js

Answer (score 0):

You can try **dayjs** library or native JS Date objects.